# Accessing html Span tag in Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

I want to access the collection of `span` tag which is having `value attribute` like below

`<span class="label_xmlvalue_row value" value="Automation_TestBundle_13thMarch">`

```
<iframe>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr class="empty">there are no items in this view</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<span class="bigger value">
<span class="text">3. Author</span>
</span>
</td>

<td>
<span class="label_xmlvalue_row value" value="Automation_TestBundle_13thMarch">
<span class="text" title="Task Name: Automation_TestBundle_13thMarch">Task Name: 
<span class="xmlvalue">Automation_TestBundle_13thMarch</span>
</span>
</span>
</td>

<td>
<span class="bigger value">
<span class="text">3. Author</span>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<span class="bigger value">
<span class="text">Reviewer</span>
</span>
</td>

<td>
<span class="label_xmlvalue_row value" value="TestBundle_13thMarch">
<span class="text" title="Task Name: TestBundle_13thMarch">Task Name: 
<span class="xmlvalue">TestBundle_13thMarch</span>
</span>
</span>
</td>

<td>
<span class="bigger value">
<span class="text">3. Author</span>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>.....</tr>


</tbody>
</table>
</body>

</html>
</iframe>
```

So I have tried few things and bringing it to your notice

```
1. driver.switchTo.Frame(element);
var ele = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("span"));
ele.Text property gives "Cannot access dead object"

2. driver.switchTo.Frame(element);
IWebElement ele =  driver.FindElements(By.TagName("span")).Where(x=>x.GetAttribute("Value").Equals("Automation_TestBundle_13thMarch")).First();

Exception thrown - Invalid Operation Exception
Inner Exception = null
Message = can't access dead object
```

1. Can we access the span tag directly without finding the html element(`/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td`)? 
If means why in this case it is throwing an exception.
2. If not please provide me an alternate solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As you have only one frame then you can use:-

```
driver.switchTo.Frame(0);
```

You can try with below xpath

```
//span/@value
```

Code:

```
ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> links = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//span/@value"));


foreach(IWebElement link in links)
{
    string text = link.Text;
    Console.WriteLine(text);
}
```

[image]

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: @ jain - No I have multiple frames. but u know i'm already switching to them

Comment: ok .... then switch them accordingly .. I have updated the code also .. have a try ..

Comment: @Jain - It throw's Invalid Selector Exception when trying to access the element via Xpath

Comment: Exception Message - The given selector //span/@value is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
InvalidSelectorError: The result of the xpath expression "//span/@value" is: [object Attr]. It should be an element.

Comment: I am able to retrieve values .. see the images I have added .. actually my c# is not so good you can try different methods to extract the data one by one.

Comment: Ok.. I tried to retrieve all the tr elements, I'm success on that

Comment: var a = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//tr")); - Can be able to retrieve all the tr elements present inside table

Comment: but couldn't be able to fetch the span tag

Comment: that's weird .. are you sure you are accessing the same frame tr?

Comment: Yeah, It seems to be like that only

Comment: When I try to access span or tr or td elements by using xpath, i can be able to retrieve that, but it results to an exception when getting the attribute value of the span tag

Comment: Not sure why this is happening in that way

Comment: I think it is throwing an exception for this line var a = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//span")).Where(x => x.GetAttribute("value").Equals("Automation_TestBundle_13thMarch")).First(); because, few span tags don't have value attribute

Comment: cant say exactly and my c# is not good while why this .First();?

Comment: @Jain- becasue it will return only the first one in the collection of elements

Comment: then why you are using FindElements .. we use FindElements in the only case where we are expecting results more than 1 .. you can use FindElement then instead of FindElements

Comment: @jain - because we cannot predict, in which row the the value will get found,

Comment: basically the value is not a static one.based on the publishing(if anything published new it will come in the first row or else it may occur in any of the row) the value will get displayed in the table row.

Answer (score 0):

First you switch on iframe

```
Driver.switchto.iframe(iframe path);
   WebElement  headobject=DriverObj.findElement(By.xpath("//head/body/table/tbody//td"));
                List<WebElement> spanobject=headobject.findElements(By.tagName("span"));
system.out.printf(spanobject.size());
                Iterator<WebElement> span=spanobject.iterator();
                while(span.hasNext()){
                WebElement span1=span.next();
                String spangettext=span1.getText();
```

Here i am perform action for get text 
you have perform your action as you wish

for click

```
span1.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your support guys, I got solution,

```
IWebElement elem = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("tr")).Where(x => x.Text.ToLower().Contains("Automation_TestBundle_13thMarch".ToLower())).First();
```

Instead of getting the attribute value, i'm just looking the text of the span tag because, `GetAttribute()` method throwing a null reference exception if the attribute is not found